# How to calculate the probability that a random function $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ satisfies $|f^{-1}(i)| \leq 2$ for each $i$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, functions

Let $A$ = {$1,2,3,4,5$} and consider the experiment that consists of the random selection of a function $f: A\rightarrow A$. Calculate the probability that the chosen function satisfies that $\left|f^{-1}(i)\right|\leq 2$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,5$. That is, each number has at most two preimages.

I know that the total number of functions possible to construct is $5^5 = 3125$,
but I don't know how to count the functions that are requested, unless I see it by cases, for example the bijective functions, which I don't know if it is the most appropriate.

Comment: Just go case by case. There are $5!$ functions for which each point has exactly one pre-image.  Now consider the case in which exactly one point has exactly two pre-images, and so on.

Comment: First of all, I considered that $i$ had two pre-images, for $i=1,\ldots,5$ and the rest had at most one pre-image. Thus obtaining $1200$ functions.
Then I considered that i and j $(i,j)$ had two pre-images, for $i=1,\ldots,5$ and $j=1,\ldots,5$, and the rest had at most one pre-image. Thus obtaining $900$ functions. Note that it is not possible to build more functions, since we would need at least $3$ elements to have two pre-images, which is impossible. It would be a total of $1200+900+120=2220$ functions
Is this calculation correct?

Comment: I agree with the $1200$ and the methodology looks good...give me a second to check the last case...

Comment: Yup, good work. If you like, you can post your own solution below.  That way people can check it and the site can take the question off the unanswered list.

Comment: $$1-\frac{5\cdot\left[\binom50+\binom51\cdot4+\binom52\cdot4^2\right]}{5^5}$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I considered that $i$ had two pre-images, for $i=1,…,5$ and the rest had at most one pre-image. Thus obtaining $1200$ functions. Then I considered that $i$ and $j$ $(i,j)$ had two pre-images, for $i=1,…,5$ and $j=1,…,5$, and the rest had at most one pre-image. Thus obtaining $900$ functions. Note that it is not possible to build more functions, since we would need at least $3$ elements to have two pre-images, which is impossible. It would be a total of $1200+900+120=2220$